# POSIXct back to character, specific format

Tags: r, date, posixct

lets say we have  a character vector of like:

```
vec <- "1/1/2000"
```

at some pont we turn this into a date via

```
newvec <- as.POSIXct("1/1/2000", format = "%d/%m/%Y")
```

Now let say we want to make it a character again we can do:

```
as.character(newvec)
[1] "2000-01-01"
```

the new format is `Y-m-d`. How can we turn newvec into `"1/1/2000"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
as.character(newvec,'%d/%m/%Y')
# [1] "01/01/2000"
```